# How can I continuously run unit tests in Visual Studio 2012 Professional?

Tags: unit-testing, ide, visual-studio-2012, test-runner

Visual Studio 2012 added [a "Run tests after build" button in the Unit Test Explorer](http://intellitect.com/turning-on-continuous-testing-in-visual-studio-11/), but it seems that option is not available in the Professional edition. In fact, my "Unit Test Explorer" is just called "Test Explorer", and doesn't have that button at all:

[image: Screenshot of Test Explorer window]

Are there any extensions which can replace this missing feature? Something that integrates with the existing test explorer UI would be ideal. (Free options are also preferred, since if I could convince my corporate overlords to shell out for VS Ultimate/Premium, this wouldn't be an issue anyway)

Answer (score 27):

I remapped my F6 key to TestExplorer.RunAllTests instead of the default of Build.BuildSolution

Build.BuildSolution gets remapped to Ctrl-Shift-B when you do that.

It works well because now my F6 reflex RunAllTests saves any modified files, builds my solution and runs my unit tests.

The only thing I had to change is my window layout so that I can see the Test Explorer Window, that way I know if any tests failed.

Updating the answer with a link to a [blog I wrote](http://jason.learmouth.ca/2013/07/how-to-run-tests-after-build-in-visual.html) about this

Comment: This approach is saving me a bunch of time. Thank you.

Comment: If the site is down, an archived page is available @ http://web.archive.org/web/20161007013353/http://jason.learmouth.ca/

Answer (score 20):

The "Run Tests After Build" and "Profile Test" features are available in Premimum and Ultimate editions of Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: I had no idea!... and there it is, the option on the Test menu staring me in the face...

Comment: This continues to be true for 2015 - available in Enterprise only - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh270865.aspx

Answer (score 9):

[NCrunch](http://www.ncrunch.net) is not free but it's well worth the money and superior to any and all test running features in Visual Studio, regardless of edition.

Comment: I have been using nCrunch since early betas. Just recently my trial period ran out. My company is working on getting us licenses, but it's a slow process. I tried MightyMoose and Test Explorer, but neither one compares. nCrunch FTW!

Comment: The link In this answer refers to NCrunch.com, which has apparently expired.  go to NCrunch.net instead.  The product is still alive and well.  I used it for a couple years while it was free, and it was fantastic.  If you're in a TDD environment, you won't want to develop without it.

Comment: Only that [NCrunch does not yet support DNX projects](https://twitter.com/remcomulder/status/697363743668363265), which if using xunit, you're then limited to the command line ([dnx-watch](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx-watch) with [xunit](http://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-started-dnx.html) is kool tho), or the VS Test Runner

Answer (score 5):

You could also have a look at http://www.continuoustests.com/ aka Mighty Moose.

It's not quite as slick as NCrunch, but it *is* free.